# What is Linux equivalent of CMD /K?

Tags: linux, bash, .desktop

There is a .desktop compilation script, that needs to remain open after terminating, in case there are errors I need to correct.  In Windows, I would run `cmd /k script.bat`, and the /k would keep a cmd window open after terminating.

In Linux, my solution is to create a bash script, that consists of the "compile" command, and a "bash" command at the end.  The .desktop file invokes the script, which in turn stays open after finishing, due to the bash command.

Is there a way to do this with a single file?  If so, I need to do either one of the following with a single command, e.g. by a command-line argument to bash:

- Make bash run a command before starting (equivalent of cmd /k command in Windows)
- Make bash start in a certain directory (I can configure the compilation to trigger when its directory is opened)
- Make the .desktop file stay open after executing its command (this is the least preferable, since I would need a second window open to correct mistakes, if any)

Please let me know if one of these is possible.

Comment: Duplicates over on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465930/prevent-gnome-terminal-from-exiting-after-execution and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution

Comment: Some terminal emulators have such an option, others don't. For example, `konsole` [has `--noclose`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/konsole.1.html)

Comment: @Celada Thank you, I couldn't find those when searching, because I was searching for `bash`, and not for `gnome-terminal`.  Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 9):

I found a way. I got it from some stackexchange site but can't find it back.

Anyway: You can abuse bash's `--init-file` option. It is intended to override using some other startup script instead of .bashrc, but you can put anything there. Combined with anonymous pipes, you can do something like this:

```
bash --init-file <(echo "your --command --here")
```

After the command ends, you'll be dropped back into bash - not a new instance of bash like with some other solutions, but the same instance.

Now, this'll skip .bashrc of course because that's what `--init-file` is for. To fix that, you get the tremendously pretty

```
bash --init-file <(echo ". \"$HOME/.bashrc\"; your --command --here")
```

Ugly, but it works :-)

**On the Windows Subsystem for Linux**

Finally, I tried doing this from Windows, but got into trouble because when you *start* `bash` to invoke the Windows Subsystem for Linux, you're still in Windows land so anonymous pipes won't work, $HOME is all wrong, and so on. My workaround for "cmd /k, but for starting the windows subsystem for linux" has become:

```
bash -c 'exec bash --init-file ^<(echo ". \"$HOME/.bashrc\"; your --command --here")'
```

Note the `^` to escape the `<` character. This will start bash (`bash -c`), immediately replace the current bash process by a new one (`exec`), which is also a bash process, now initialized as discussed before, from within Linux land.

I made a batch file called `bash-k.cmd` in my PATH so i can invoke it easily, with this inside it:

```
@bash -c 'exec bash --init-file ^<(echo ". \"$HOME/.bashrc\"; %*")'
```

It allows me to do `bash-k cowsay hello` and things will work

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @skrebbel that is a very helpful command, here is are .reg file codes to add a `Bash Console Here` right-click context menu if you have **Windows Subsystem for Linux**

**AddContext.reg:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\BashConsoleHere]
@="Bash Console Here"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,4c,00,4f,00,43,00,41,00,4c,00,41,00,50,00,50,00,44,00,41,\
  00,54,00,41,00,25,00,5c,00,6c,00,78,00,73,00,73,00,5c,00,62,00,61,00,73,00,\
  68,00,2e,00,69,00,63,00,6f,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\BashConsoleHere\command]
@="bash -c 'exec bash --init-file <(echo \". \"$HOME/.bashrc\"\")'"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\BashConsoleHere]
@="Bash Console Here"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,4c,00,4f,00,43,00,41,00,4c,00,41,00,50,00,50,00,44,00,41,\
  00,54,00,41,00,25,00,5c,00,6c,00,78,00,73,00,73,00,5c,00,62,00,61,00,73,00,\
  68,00,2e,00,69,00,63,00,6f,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\BashConsoleHere\command]
@="bash -c 'exec bash --init-file <(echo \". \"$HOME/.bashrc\"\")'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\BashConsoleHere]
@="Bash Console Here"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\BashConsoleHere\command]
@="bash -c 'exec bash --init-file <(echo \". \"$HOME/.bashrc\"\")'"
```

**Undo.reg:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\BashConsoleHere]
@="Bash Console Here"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,4c,00,4f,00,43,00,41,00,4c,00,41,00,50,00,50,00,44,00,41,\
  00,54,00,41,00,25,00,5c,00,6c,00,78,00,73,00,73,00,5c,00,62,00,61,00,73,00,\
  68,00,2e,00,69,00,63,00,6f,00,00,00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\BashConsoleHere\command]
@="nircmd elevate cmd /c cd \"%V\" && bash.exe"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\BashConsoleHere]
@="Bash Console Here"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,4c,00,4f,00,43,00,41,00,4c,00,41,00,50,00,50,00,44,00,41,\
  00,54,00,41,00,25,00,5c,00,6c,00,78,00,73,00,73,00,5c,00,62,00,61,00,73,00,\
  68,00,2e,00,69,00,63,00,6f,00,00,00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\BashConsoleHere\command]
@="nircmd elevate cmd /c cd \"%1\" && bash.exe"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\BashConsoleHere]
@="Bash Console Here"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\BashConsoleHere\command]
@="nircmd elevate cmd /c cd \"%1\" && bash.exe"
```